# Find A Repeating Number And Adding Text

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I just begun using excel and I have a list of different numbers. So I want every time I type a new number on A to automatically add "The number is "+number on B, and then on C a Yes or No depending if the number is already given. Can this be done automatically every time or do I have to drag the above box in the current? Any help?

Comment: Please share demo data and desired results. Is B just concatenating the number in A to the text, or something else going on. Not sure what you mean by C.... what are you comparing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a Table, you can have new rows auto-populate the formulas in each column.

Put your cursor anywhere in your list of numbers (with a column header in the first row), then press Ctrl+T to create a Table.

Supposing your table looks like this and is called Table1:

[image]

Then the formula in the Description column (you can just type it into cell B2), would be this:

```
="The number is "&[@Number]
```

Because we are using a Table, it shows as `[@Number]` instead of `A2`.

Then the formula in column C would be this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF([Number],[@Number])>1,"Yes","")
```

That is to say, "In the number column, count all the occurrences of the value in the current row. If that count is greater than 1 (i.e. if the number is in more than one row), then show the word 'Yes'. Otherwise, show nothing."

You can see that at the beginning, there are no rows with the word yes. But if I add a row with a value that already exists, they will both show Yes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Step--1.. In Column A : Enter the numbers in Cell A1, A2, A3,....so on.
Step--2.. In Cell B1 enter the formula : B1=" The number is "&A1
Step--3.. Formula in C1=If( Countif($A$1:A1,A1)>1, "Number Already Exists", "" )
Step--4-- Copy formula of B1 and C1 down the rows.

Thanks.